# Entity Framework Inserts - Large object performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

I have a pretty simple schema, that has multi-level relationships within it. For example schema looks like this

> An OFFICE table has a list of buildings, a list of Cafeterias, a list
>   of CoffeeShops Each building can have a list of Floors. Each Floor can
>   have a list of rooms etc.

```
dbCcontext.Offices.Add(well);
dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

In some scenarios I end up with an Office entity with 1000's of buildings and each building can have 1000's of floors etc. When I have such an Office object and try to Insert it to the database using `DbContext.Add` and `SaveChanges()`, EF takes about 4 seconds to insert. I used EF profiler to see the SQL statements, and there seems to be more than 2000 individual `Insert` statements.

Are the individual inserts the reason for the slow Inserts, if so what are my alternatives?

I am using Entity Framework 6 (code-first)

Comment: You should show us your code. Anyway EF does all those inserts in a single transaction, and 4 secs for 2000 inserts with the related FK and PK to check for integrity doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: Disable detecting changes. Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

Comment: I tried all these  context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;. But none of them seemed to make any difference

Comment: @Matteo, 4 seconds is not bad for 2000 inserts? I was hoping it was something stupid that am missing

Comment: 4 secs is not bad, for better performance you may try bulk insert plugins for EntityFramework.

Comment: though your query will take 4 secs to perform but you can put that in background using db.SaveChangesAsync();
By the way 4 sec seems to be good, dont get too greedy :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts that can have some performance issues.

- The Add to ChangeTracker
- The `INSERT` to Database

## The Add to ChangeTracker

I will assume here that you have some performance issue, but the first thing to check will be to verify if you have a performance issue or not.

> An OFFICE table has a list of buildings, a list of Cafeterias, a list of CoffeeShops Each building can have a list of Floors. Each Floor can have a list of rooms etc.

One problem when you add an entity that has A LOT of related entities that has also related entities (must be very high!) will be how to DetectChanges work. It will suffer from some performance.

Adding in order using AddRange:

- Room
- Floors
- Building
- Office

*(Child to parent instead of the parent only)*

May lead to some performance improvement. More you have related entities, better this technic will become. You must have several thousands of entities to see the difference.

It's longer to code than a simple `Offices.Add` but we already worked with a client that has a similar scenario (had over 100k entities) and the performance improved by over 50x times!

## The `INSERT` to Database

In your case, you report more than 2000 individual insert which means 2000 database round-trip. The only way to improve this performance is to reduce the number of database round-trip required.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but adds bulk operations method extensions to your `DbContext` :

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Only a few database round-trips will be required and may lead to performance improvement by 25x time and more!

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Bulk Operations
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
   options => options.IncludeGraph = true;
});
context.BulkMerge(customers, options => {
   options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```